# Azure Durable Function using Python runtime

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

We are using Azure Functions for some of our ETL processing and have deployed multiple functions (cosmosdb trigger) and http based. Since some of the ETL jobs(triggered by http) take a long time to finish, we are exploring job based approach. It seems durable function will be appropriate. However, it is still in preview.

Does anyone has any idea about the stability of this feature with python runtime and when will it be available as GA ?

Comment: Hi, if dont have more doubts, can we end this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the status of python durable azure function, you can follow this announcement:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/durable-functions-now-supports-python/

Azure Function teams originally planned make it GA at June of 2020. Although it is not in GA status now, it should be soon.(If the preview goes well)

My suggestion is that you should not put the python-based durable function into production now because its stability is not guaranteed, and there is no good documentation support.

Have a look of the current known limitations:

https://github.com/azure/azure-functions-durable-python#current-limitations